# Java Spring Boot: How to enable pagination for dependency request

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am building an REST API with Spring Boot. The question is really simple, how can I enable pagination for dependency request?

This how the results look for a non dependency request  `http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributes`:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "dimensionAttribute" : [ {
      "name" : "SollFreitag",
      "description" : "Sollstunden Freitags",
      "dataType" : "DEC",
      "hasHistory" : true,
      "hasTrigger" : null,
      "allowInterface" : true,
      "readOnly" : null,
      "discrete" : null,
      "mandatory" : false,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributes/20"
        },
        "dimensionAttribute" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributes/20"
        },
        "dimension" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributes/20/dimension"
        },
        "dimensionAttributeValue" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributes/20/dimensionAttributeValue"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "first" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributes?page=0&size=20"
    },
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributes{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "next" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributes?page=1&size=20"
    },
    "last" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributes?page=1&size=20"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/dimensionAttributes"
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributes/search"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 35,
    "totalPages" : 2,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

But running an dependency request (in this case its "dimensionAttributeValue" ) `http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributes/20/dimensionAttributeValue`, the `page` section, as well as the `next` url and other links are missing.

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "dimensionAttributeValue" : [ {
      "chrValue" : "Mihal, Matus",
      "intValue" : null,
      "decValue" : null,
      "datValue" : null,
      "startDate" : null,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributeValues/18993"
        },
        "dimensionAttributeValue" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributeValues/18993"
        },
        "lstValue" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributeValues/18993/lstValue"
        },
        "dimensionAttribute" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributeValues/18993/dimensionAttribute"
        },
        "masterData" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributeValues/18993/masterData"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/dimensionAttributes/1/dimensionAttributeValue?page=0,&size=1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your controller class and resource assembler class?

Comment: I don't have writen a controller class and what is the assembler class? 
And no i could retrieve many dimensionAttributeValue objects. Could be hundreds. Have a close look: `{
  "_embedded" : {
    "dimensionAttributeValue" : [ many objects are possible ], [..] }`